# Rust - writing to indices of a vector across multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety, buffer

I have a circular ring buffer (implemented as a vector) where I want one thread to periodically write to the ring buffer and another to periodically read from the ring buffer. Is it possible to create a vector that can be read and written at the same time so long as threads accessing the vector are not at the same index?

What I am hoping to achieve:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

    let vec = Arc::new(vec![Mutex::new(1), Mutex::new(2),Mutex::new(3)]);

    {
        let vec = vec.clone();
        thread::spawn(move|| {
            let mut s2 = *vec.get_mut(2).unwrap().lock().unwrap();
            s2 = 7;
        });
    }

    println!("{}", vec[2].lock().unwrap());
}
```

Compiler output is:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: variable `s2` is assigned to, but never used
  --> src/main.rs:12:21
   |
12 |             let mut s2 = *vec.get_mut(2).unwrap().lock().unwrap();
   |                     ^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
   = note: consider using `_s2` instead

warning: value assigned to `s2` is never read
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             s2 = 7;
   |             ^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
   = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?

error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |             let mut s2 = *vec.get_mut(2).unwrap().lock().unwrap();
   |                           ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `std::sync::Arc<std::vec::Vec<std::sync::Mutex<i32>>>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Foiled by the rust type system trying to prevent a race condition :(

What I don't want

- An implementation that involves having the lock scope including the vector.
- An atomic read and write to the vector is not an option since the vector will contain images.

Link to playground:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b5efe91bdd45c658d11f1cefb16045e

Comment: Have you considered not implementing yourself and instead using something like https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.2/crossbeam/sync/chase_lev/index.html ? Not sure if that's applicable to your case, but API-wise it sounds like what you'd want.

Comment: Side note: prefer using `Arc::clone()` over `arc.clone()`, so as to prevent confusion over whether you are cloning the vector or the Arc.

Comment: Also, s2 is now a value not a pointer, so writing it has no effect. You probably wanted to dereference s2 as `*s2 = 6;` not on the line above.

Comment: Regarding your error, you didn't need to get_mut on the vector at all. Locking a mutex doesn't require &mut.

Comment: Regarding your question: your code doesn't seem to resemble anything about ring buffers. By "periodically read from the ring buffer", do you mean it just *reads*, or does it *poll* (hence remove) something from the ring buffer? Please clarify.

Comment: First good step would be to get rid of a Vec by extracting a raw pointer from it and managing synchronization yourself. If you aren't willing to do that, you won't gain anything, whether that is knowledge or performance, and you might aswell just be using a crate that already did it for you. It's very easy to synchronize writing to a ring buffer using nothing but a single atomic index, reading out of it takes more thought, but it's doable.

Comment: In more recent releases of the `crossbeam` crate, [`ArrayQueue`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.3/crossbeam/queue/struct.ArrayQueue.html) provides a lock-free ring buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to use `std::sync::RwLock`, because it allows multiple readers to read data simultaneously.

Second, spawning threads can lead to performance bottlenecks in your code. Try to use thread pool.

Of course, the exact choice will vary depending on the result of benchmarks, but those are general recommendations.

Your code is mostly correct, except one crucial part. You are using `Mutex` which implements [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) pattern and also provides thread-safety.

Interior mutability moves compiletime checks of `XOR` borrowing rule (either N immutable borrows or just one mutable) to the run-time. So, `Mutex` ensures that any time there exists only one reader or only one writer.

When you try to get mutable reference from `vec`, like this

```
vec.get_mut(..)
```

You are essentially ignoring benefits provided by interior mutability. Compiler can't guarantee that `XOR` rule is not broken, because you borrow `vec` as mutable.

Obvious solution is to borrow `vec` as immutable and using `Mutex` to safeguard against race condition and don't utilize compiler borrowing rules.

```
let mut s2 = vec
    .get(2) // Get immutable reference to second item
    .unwrap() // Ensure that it exists
    .lock() // Lock mutex. 
    .unwrap(); // Ensure mutex isn't poisoned.

// s2 is now `std::sync::MutexGuard<i32>`, which implements `std::ops::DerefMut`, 
// so it can get us mutable reference to data.
*s2 = 7;
```

Comment: If you have multiple readers accessing the same location you're also trying to write to, `RwLock` can starve the writer because the reads may overlap. It's not quite as simple as "use `RwLock` when you have multiple readers". Otherwise, good answer.